# How to Insert Image (byte) into pdf (byte) using ItextSharp

Tags: c#, asp.net, itext

I have a pdf(byte) stored in database table and I have also stored image(byte) in database table.

Now I want to read pdf file from database and insert image (byte) into pdf file and want to save new pdf (byte) into new table. 
It gives error as "The Document has no page."
I have used below code:

```
 string fileName = "~/AuthDoc/" + Convert.ToString(consentMain.AppointmentId) +".pdf";                              
            string newFile = System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.MapPath(fileName);
            PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(consentDoc); // get pdf byte from datbase
            Rectangle size = reader.GetPageSizeWithRotation(1);
            Document document = new Document(size);
            // open the writer
            FileStream fs = new FileStream(newFile, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write);
            PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, fs);
            document.Open();



            // PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(consentDoc);
          //   FileStream fs = new FileStream(newFile, FileMode.Create);
            var stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, fs);
            var pdfContentByte = stamper.GetOverContent(1);
            iTextSharp.text.Image PatientSign = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(consentMain.PatientSign); // image from database
            PatientSign.SetAbsolutePosition(100, 100);
            pdfContentByte.AddImage(PatientSign);

            document.Close();
            fs.Close();
            writer.Close();
            reader.Close();
            byte[] bytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(newFile);
            return bytes;
```

Comment: Probably not going to fix your problem, but I wouldn't call `fs.Close()` before `writer.Close()`. If you put disposables in a `using` block you'd automatically force yourself to use the right order.

Comment: Your code is old, in the sense that you're not using the most recent version of iText, and it's awkward in the sense that you use the `Document` *and* the `PdfStamper` class. Those classes were mutually exclusive in the version of iText you're using. Why don't you upgrade?

Comment: Start by removing all references to `Document` and `PdfWriter` (throw away those lines completely), then make sure you close the `PdfStamper` object: `stamper.Close()`. Or... throw away *all of your code* and start anew with iText 7 for .NET.

Comment: Thanks @BrunoLowagie , Now it works fine.

Comment: I made my comment an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have too much code, and one important line is missing. I took your code and removed all the lines that aren't necessary (and that make your file corrupt):

```
string fileName = "~/AuthDoc/" + Convert.ToString(consentMain.AppointmentId) +".pdf";                              
string newFile = System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.MapPath(fileName);
PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(consentDoc); // get pdf byte from datbase
FileStream fs = new FileStream(newFile, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write);
var stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, fs);
var pdfContentByte = stamper.GetOverContent(1);
iTextSharp.text.Image PatientSign = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(consentMain.PatientSign); // image from database
PatientSign.SetAbsolutePosition(100, 100);
pdfContentByte.AddImage(PatientSign);
stamper.Close();
reader.Close();
byte[] bytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(newFile);
return bytes;
```

I also added the missing line: `stamper.Close();`

Comment: Thanks @Bruno, Code woks fine

Comment: Hi Using your code I can add images on first page.  How to add image on second page of pdf?

Comment: Do you see the line `stamper.GetOverContent(1);`? The 1 indicates that you want to add something on the first page. If you want to add something on the second page, you need `stamper.GetOverContent(2);` If there is no second page, you need the `InsertPage()` method to insert an extra page.

Comment: Can you please look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48560523/how-to-write-text-on-second-and-third-page-of-exiting-pdf-using-itextsharp. I have an issue to write text on extingin pdf file if pf has more then 1 page. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: I don't understand that question. It's not well-written. You should rephrase it so that a 10-year old can understand it. Right now, it's written as if you expect that someone can read your mind. **Also: you are using an old version of iText. Why didn't you start using iText 7 instead?**

Comment: sorry for my bad English. I have just updated question. As our code is very large and we have use ItextSharp in more than 15 -
 20 foms. If I update Version then other code will be affected.

Comment: Do you have a commercial license for your use of iText? Note that such a license is mandatory if you use iText in a closed source context. You can only use iText without paying in the context of an open source project. If you don't have a commercial license, please let me know where I can download your code as open source.

Comment: You use iText from Nuget manager, but you didn't install the right package. Read [the download page on the iText web site](https://developers.itextpdf.com/itext7/download-and-install-information/NET). Downloading a package from Nuget doesn't mean you can just use the software any way you like it. If you read the license (that's the AGPL in the case of iText), you should know that there are certain obligations, such as open sourcing the code you write. Are you meeting those obligations?