# How to write text on different page based on text of exiting pdf using itextsharp

Tags: asp.net, pdf, c#-4.0, itext

How to write Text on different pages on exiting pdf which have more then 1 page.
For example 'Hitesh Second Page' I want to write this word on second page
'Hitesh Third Page' I want to write this word on Third page

Below code work only for pdf which have one page.

```
   string fileName = "test.pdf";
                string oldFile = System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.MapPath("~/AuthDoc/CoverPage.pdf");
                string newFile = System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.MapPath(fileName);
                // open the reader
                PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(oldFile);
                Rectangle size = reader.GetPageSizeWithRotation(1);
                Document document = new Document(size);

                // open the writer
                FileStream fs = new FileStream(newFile, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write);
                PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, fs);
                document.Open();

                // the pdf content
                PdfContentByte cb = writer.DirectContent;

                // select the font properties
                BaseFont bf = BaseFont.CreateFont(BaseFont.HELVETICA, BaseFont.CP1252, BaseFont.NOT_EMBEDDED);
                cb.SetColorFill(BaseColor.DARK_GRAY);
                cb.SetFontAndSize(bf, 8);
                string text = "";
                cb.BeginText();
                text = "Hitesh Third Page";
                cb.ShowTextAligned(3, text,500,500, 0);
                cb.EndText();

  cb.BeginText();
                text = "Hitesh Second Page";
                cb.ShowTextAligned(2, text,500,500, 0);
                cb.EndText();
                PdfImportedPage page = writer.GetImportedPage(reader, 1);
                cb.AddTemplate( page, 0, 0);             
                document.Close();
                fs.Close();
                writer.Close();
                reader.Close();
                byte[] bytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(newFile);
                return bytes;
```

Thanks,
Hitesh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using a `Document` / `PdfWriter` pair to create a document, you create the pages in their final order, i.e. you first create the first page, then the second, then the third, ...

In your code you appear to try to start by creating the third page and then continue by creating the second one. You'll have to sort the code accordingly.

As soon as you have sorted your code, you can use the `Document` method `NewPage` to switch to the next page:

```
document.NewPage();
```

Beware, though, iText ignores the `NewPage` call if there is no content whatsoever on the page in question. To override this, you can make iText believe it is not empty using the `PdfWriter` property `PageEmpty` before calling `NewPage`:

```
writer.PageEmpty = false;
document.NewPage();
```

---

That been said, though...

> How to write Text on different pages on exiting pdf

For such a task you should not use a `Document` / `PdfWriter` pair to start with, use a `PdfReader` / `PdfStamper` pair! In a `PdfStamper` you can quite freely jump between pages...